# Why Right Associativity doesn't work with the declaration statement

Tags: c

```
int a=b=c=10;  //invalid statement
```

But following are valid statements

```
int a,b,c;
a=b=c=10;
```

First one is invalid as b assigned to a even before b got its value.

But the second case is valid as equal(=) sign is having right associative i.e
"=" sign will start getting preference from the right side.

My question is: why doesn't Right Associativity apply in the first case?
Does it mean that Associativity doesn't work with the declaration statement?
I need more clarity on this.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't work because it isn't syntactically correct. As you show in the second example, more than one variable of a type are declared using commas as a separator. If instead `b` and `c` are already declared then things work fine. For example this works:

```
int b,c;
int a=b=c=10;
```

You can even do this (at least with VS2010 compiler):

```
int b,c,a=b=c=10;
```

Mind you I'd say that looks **BAD**, and advise against it.

Comment: It means in the statement where declaration and assignment happens in the same line, it expect declaration of all variables to be done before.

Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 4):

If it'd be not just an exercise but you had tested this with a real compiler, you probably would have given us a bit more information of actually *what* displeases the compiler.

Part of the answer would be to notice the two different roles of the `=` operator. One is assignment and one is initialization. Your example

```
int a = b = c = 10;
```

is equivalent to

```
int a = (b = (c = 10));
```

So the two `=` on the right are assignments and not initializations. And in an assignment the left hand side must be well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Variables need to be declared first and then assigned a value or used in expressions.